How do you merge unused verticies to a ring of verticies
Ok, so I am a bit new to blender and am struggeling with a problem. I am making a file holder with a screw on cap and that is working fine. The problem is that I used a seperate mesh to make the threads. I did remove most of the excess verticies and everything is fine except that in cura it creates a face across the top. I believe it creates this face because of the extra verticies that are under the mesh. Is there a way to remove excess verticies and marge all connecting points to where the faces of the mesh are connecting?

Would you mind giving us any hint of how your geometry looks? And where you think the excess vertices are and which area makes problems? At least a single screenshot so that we get an idea what is going on there?

i strongly recommend providing two images: 1) what you have now 2) what you wanna have to make it crystal clear what you want. Thx for your understanding.

Hi, Korban, welcome.. it does sound as if you might have to plan ahead for good topology when modelling this one.. it turns out that a picture displaying the wireframe is pretty essential here. You can also share your .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ . Without at least an illustration, this post is flagged 'unclear'.

Hi, sorry about the confusion. My problem lies where the threads meet the rest of the face. Here is the wireframe mesh: https://files.chipmunk.land/i5qykhex.png           Here is the solid mesh: https://files.chipmunk.land/z8is0p7h.png                 Here is the link to the blendere exchange: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Gk8k4e6l/

You could use boolean but anyway it would need some rework afterwards so you can do it manually instead:
Hide all the faces except the screw, use the Bisect tool to cut off its bottom:

Unhide the rest, cut off the top faces of the cylinder:

CtrlE to Bridge Edge Loops the screw and cylinder:

